# mouseChildren = false not working very well for me

Tags: flash, addeventlistener, addchild

Happy new year btw !

I want to separate event handling from a container and it child. So as you can see, my source code is very simple :

```
    package  {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;

    public class test extends Sprite{

        public function test() {
            var container:Sprite = new Sprite();  // my container
            container.graphics.beginFill(0, 1);  // whatever the color
            container.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100); // origin at 0,0
            container.graphics.endFill();
            addChild(container);

            var decor:Sprite = new Sprite();  // and it child
            decor.graphics.beginFill(0, 1);  // whatever the color
            decor.graphics.drawRect(200, 200, 100, 100);  // origin at 200,200
            decor.graphics.endFill();
            container.addChild(decor);
            container.mouseChildren = false;
            container.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, onOver, false, 0, true);
        }
        private function onOver(e: MouseEvent):void {
            trace("ROLL trace");
        }
    }
}
```

When I roll over the container object, I've got the trace (OK for me).
BUT When I roll over the decor object, I've got the trace too (not what I want).
I just want the container to be triggered by the mouse event, not it child.
So what's happened to my mouseChildren = false....? I don't understand...

Answer (score 4):

The `decor` object is a member of `container`, and therefore it is evaluated along with any other content within `container`.

`mouseChildren = false;` is not a way to completely disable mouse events, but to reduce complexity within composite display objects: A mouse event is still fired, but the event's `target` property will not contain a reference to the child object the mouse actually rolled over, but only to the parent that the property was set on.

If you want `decor`to be completely ignored, use `decor.mouseEnabled = false;`instead.

Comment: +1 right on. Just some complimentary info for @nouatzi, from the language reference http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#mouseChildren. Always check the AS3 docs! They're full of great nfo.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried mouseEnabled = false, and it's not working either.
In another forum, a guys told me that ['a filled object within container will trigger the event handler'](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?370293-mouseChildren-false-not-wroking-very-well-fo-me...&highlight=mousechildren).
So his solution is to have the container, and create 2 children : one handling the mouse event, and the other one as decor.

And it's working pretty well.